# Using autofill on multiple columns with filtered list

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to optimize my work with autofill formulas in sorted list.
I tried a few options and found out that Autofill and Filldown didn't work as expected on sorted list.
So I star using property - SpecialCells and actually it works fine on single column. But some times I need to fill multiple columns from 2 to 8 and if I change the range from single to few columns everything went not as I wanted to.

Formulas sets in the first row of filtered list.

So in this case everything is fine

```
Range("B17:B8196").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = Range("B17").FormulaR1C1
```

But if I try that code everything went wrong

```
Range("B17:C8196").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = Range("B17:C17").FormulaR1C1
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks you all for answering! :)

Found two ways to solve this problem.

1. I'm not expected but obvious by just copying:

```
    Sub FFF()
       Range("A10:K10").Copy Range("A10:K1000")
    End Sub
```

2. Cycle with visible cells.

```
    Sub MultiFill
       Dim TheCell as range
          For Each TheCell In Range ("A11:K1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
             TheCell.FormulaR1C1 = Cells(10, TheCell.Column).FormulaR1C1
    End Sub
```